# Simplifying Expressions with Radicals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> $$
> \begin{split}
> \sqrt2 - \frac1{\sqrt2 - \dfrac1{\sqrt2 - \dfrac1{\sqrt2 - 1}}}
>  &= \sqrt2 - \frac1{\sqrt2 - \dfrac1{\sqrt2 - \dfrac{\sqrt2 + 1}{2-1}}}\\
>  &= \sqrt2 - \frac1{\sqrt2 - \dfrac1{\sqrt2 - \left(\sqrt2 + 1\right)}}\\
>  &= \sqrt2 - \frac1{\sqrt2 + 1}\\
>  &= \sqrt2 - \left(\sqrt2 - 1\right)\\
>  &= 1
> \end{split}
> $$

Hi, I do not understand the first step we have come to. I tried to lead to a common denominator but ended up confused. Please show how to come to the first step of solving this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to remember that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ so you get
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt2-1}
 = \frac{1}{\sqrt2-1} \times \frac{\sqrt2 + 1}{\sqrt2+1}
 = \frac{\sqrt2 + 1}{\left(\sqrt2\right)^2 - 1^2}
 = \frac{\sqrt2 + 1}{2 - 1}
 = \sqrt2 + 1
$$

Comment: Is it that we would come to denominator 1? So do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Boujozo yes, correct